# Override usr-full-name with .dir-locals

Tags: org-mode, org-export, directory-local-variables

I've been trying to override the `user-full-name` by setting it in `.dir-locals`

```
((org-mode . ((org-export-with-date . nil)
          (user-full-name . "Fullname")
          (org-export-with-author . t)
          (org-cite-export-processors . "csl ieee.csl")
          (org-cite-global-bibliography . ("bibliography.bib")))))
```

All the other variables work fine when exporting, but it's still picking up the name of the logged-in user ("user"). From my current buffer with `C-h v` I get the following

```
user-full-name is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.

Its value is "Fullname"
Original value was "user"
Local in buffer thesis.org; global value is "user"

The full name of the user logged in.

  This variable’s value is directory-local, set by the file
  ‘/home/user/Projects/thesis/.dir-locals.el’.
  You can customize this variable.
  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 19.29.
```

So is it possible to actually override it from `.dir-locals`? If not, what is the best way to make it work?

EDIT - I'm using `org-latex-export-to-pdf`, but also `org-html-export-to-html`

EDIT 2 - The value of `org-publish-project-alist` is `nil`

```
org-publish-project-alist is a variable defined in ‘ox-publish.el’.

Its value is nil
```

Comment: I think you’re going to need to include more details about what you were doing. What format are you exporting to?

Comment: What is the value of `org-publish-project-alist`? If this variable is set correctly, it can contain a value which overrides `user-full-name`. Use `C-h v` to view the help for the variable to see how to use it.